# Adding compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0' but it Android studio doesn't sync

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have added  `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'` , but my android studio has failed to sync, i have even read **firebase UI**  documentations, but still am still facing the same problem. How can i fix this problem
Below is my `gradle file`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oerrride.we.huzykamz.administrator_party"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
   // compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
   // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.1'

    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the kind of error i have(**Picture**) .

[image: This is my Error of Android Studio]

Comment: click `install repository and sync project`

Comment: Update Google Repository!!